# pex regenerate test

Tags: .net, pex

I have already generated pex testing classes for a particular class. However I have changed this class due to refactoring and logic changes but I do not think that the current pex generated test class now cover everything.

How can i force pex to regenerate the individual test classes for a parent?

Comment: What is a "generated test class"? I am not familiar with that term in relation to Pex.

Comment: It is main stub class that other generated class use to test the validity of the code. Sorry I'm new to Pex and probably am using the wrong term.

Comment: Does "run custom tool" on the moles file work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed as follows:

1. Right-click on the Pex test class (assume it's called `MyClass_Test`) and select **Pex/Delete Generated Tests In Class**.  This will remove any tests from the `MyClass_Test.g.cs` file.
2. Right-click in the test class again and select **Run Pex Explorations**.  The `MyClass_Test.g.cs` will then be populated with the generated tests.

(In theory you don't need step 1, but it allows you to verify the tests are removed before being regenerated).